# writeStream of spark generates many small files

Tags: scala, apache-spark, spark-structured-streaming

I am using Spark Structured Streaming (2.3) to write parquet data to buckets in the cloud ( Google Cloud Storage). 
I am using the following function :

```
def writeStreaming(data: DataFrame, format: String, options: Map[String, String], partitions: List[String]): DataStreamWriter[Row] = {
var dataStreamWrite = data.writeStream .format(format).options(options).trigger(Trigger.ProcessingTime("120 seconds"))

if (!partitions.isEmpty)
  dataStreamWrite = ddataStreamWrite.partitionBy(partitions: _*)

dataStreamWrite
```

}

Unfortunately, with this approach, I am getting many small files.

I tried to use the trigger approach in order to avoid this, but this didn't work too. Do you have any idea about how to handle this, please ? 
Thanks a lot

Comment: Can you explain your problem in details ? How many files are getting created ? at what interval and with what data ? Are you writing output of each batch to a file through spark streaming ? Where are these files being written ? in HDFS ?

Answer (score 1):

The reason that you have many small files despite using **trigger** can be your dataframe having many partitions. To reduce the the parquet to 1 file/ 2 mins, you can **coalesce** to one partition before writing Parquet files.

```
var dataStreamWrite = data
    .coalesce(1)
    .writeStream 
    .format(format)
    .options(options)
    .trigger(Trigger.ProcessingTime("120 seconds"))
```